# we were listed on/we were listed in

Tags: prepositions

if the company is listed on/in the list of the survey/study etc, is it 'we were listed in the...' or 'we were listed on the...'

there are few discussions on this already but no grammar explanation that I can find.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

Just think of a list as a single sheet of paper. It is two-dimensional (2D). It has no depth; you can't get inside a single sheet of paper. Thus your company's name can only be **on** it.

Now think of a directory: a bunch of lists; a book with multiple pages. It has depth; it's three-dimensional (3D). Your company's name is on one of those lists, and that list is **in** the directory.

Therefore:

> Your company's name is **on** the list.
>   Your company's name is listed **in** the directory.